# Touch draw events and HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm trying to write a canvas element that can be 'draw' on with the mouse and mobile (iOS/Android).

here is my bind code:

```
// Mouse based interface
    $(drawing.canvas).bind('mousedown', drawing.drawStart);
    $(drawing.canvas).bind('mousemove', drawing.draw);
    $(drawing.canvas).bind('mouseup', drawing.drawEnd);
    $('body').bind('mouseup', drawing.drawEnd);

    $(drawing.canvas).bind('touchstart', drawing.drawStart);
    $(drawing.canvas).bind('touchmove', drawing.draw);
    $(drawing.canvas).bind('touchend', drawing.drawEnd);
```

Works with computer (PC, Mac) but not mobile (iOS/Android). I also tried `addEventListener` for the `touch*` events but no joy.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you have tried `canvas.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onTouchStart, false);`? Ignore jQuery completely for now, just try to get that working.

Comment: adding the black rectangle code worked, but it didin't work for the drawing of lines,etc. So I wonder if it is the drawing functions that aren't working or something.

Comment: It most likely is something else that is causing the problem them. Start whittling things down in your code until you get a working version, then work back up from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is either a sytax error or a jQuery problem. Distilled down, `canvas.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onTouchStart, false);` works just fine for android:

http://jsfiddle.net/tQW2L/

(on touch it paints a large black rectangle to confirm that it works)